# Adding third parameter to ViewExecutable doesn't work

Tags: views

I've created a Controller to get all content teaser of a specific type and in a specific language.

```
namespace Drupal\xxxxxx\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

use Drupal\views\Views;

class ContentTeaserController extends ControllerBase {

public function getTeaser(Request $request) {
    $params = [];

    $quantity = $request->query->get('quantity');
    $nodetypes = $request->query->get('nodetypes');
    $tags = $request->query->get('tags');
    $style = $request->query->get('style');
    $page = $request->query->get('page');
    $language = $request->query->get('language'); // <---

    $view = Views::getView('contentteaser');
    $view->setDisplay($style);
    $view->setItemsPerPage($quantity);
    $view->setOffset($page * $quantity);

    $arguments = [
        (($tags) ? $tags : '*'),
        (($nodetypes) ? $nodetypes : null),
        (($language) ? $language : 'en'), // <---
    ];
    $view->setArguments($arguments);

    $view->execute();
    $result = $view->result;


    $renderableView = $view->buildRenderable(null, array('language' => $arguments[2]), false);



    $renderableView['#embed'] = TRUE;
    $content = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderableView);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($content);
    return $response;
  }

}
```

I only added the two lines marked by `// <---`.

So when I call the route i configured for this controller, I only get the results in German.

I also tried to set the arguments statically by replacing the `$arguments` array by

```
$arguments = [
        #(($tags) ? $tags : '*'),
        #(($nodetypes) ? $nodetypes : null),
        #(($language) ? $language : 'en'),
        '*',
        'employee_article+event+news',
        'ru',
    ];
```

I must add; When I'm configuring the view in the Drupal backend and use the live preview at the bottom of the page, everything works fine.

My thought is, that it's the renderer that doesn't work properly.

This is the configuration of the View.

[image: Basic configuration]

[image: Proof that the view works well]

Comment: Any reason you are using a regular Symfony response over returning a build array?

Comment: Because I get the following error when I try to return `$content`: `LogicException: The controller must return a response (Object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup) given). in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (line 162 of vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php).`

Comment: You shouldn't do what the error message suggests, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199855, return the unrendered `$renderableView` instead.

Comment: Thank you @4k4 but I still get the result in german.

Comment: It's hard to tell, you have a lot of details about the controller, this is the reason the comments are about what is wrong there, but you don't provide any details about the view.

Comment: I must say, adding parameters to `$view->buildRender` was just a try; I was like "Hey, I haven't found what I should add as 2nd param but maybe it works"

Comment: buildRender() expects as 2nd param an array of all three arguments. But it doesn't make sense to first execute the view and then build a render element, which then would execute the view again when rendered.

Comment: Well, $view->execute() was just a try, to see in wich language the view is being processed. I'm not using $result anywhere.

Comment: OK, that is what I meant which doesn't make sense. If you don't use the result then the arguments you set in this part of the code don't have any effect. Important is what you provide as 2nd param in buildRender().